# Sizes of square matrices such that $\mathrm{A}^2=-\mathrm I$ does not exist

Tags: matrices

This question [Prove that there is no 5 × 5 matrix A such that $A^2 = −I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799686/prove-that-there-is-no-5-%C3%97-5-matrix-a-such-that-a2-%E2%88%92i)
Raises the questions:

For what values of n $n \times n$  matrix $A$ there is no $\mathrm {A}$ exists s.t. $\mathrm {A}^2=-\mathrm {I}$

or more generally

For what values of $\mathrm {B},p$, $n \times n$  matrix there is no $\mathrm {A}$ exists s.t. $A^p=\mathrm {B}$

Comment: You take the determinant and get $\det(A)^2 = (-1)^n$, impossible if $n$ is odd over the reals.

Comment: @Arjang Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $n$ is odd. For example, $det(A)^2=det(A^2)=(-1)^n$, so whenever $n$ is odd, you need a square root of $-1$.

Comment: This is half the proof, it leaves the case of $n$ even undetermined.

Answer (score 2):

Since for A real $$\det(A^2)=[\det(A)]^2\ge0$$ such $A$ doesn't exist for all $n$ odd and $B$ such that $\det(B)<0$.

Comment: This is half the proof, it leaves the case of $n$ even undetermined.

Comment: Indeed fon n even we can’t conclude anything in general, whereas for n odd we gave a criteria to exclude the existence of a solution .